# why does serila data transmission skips perticular data pattern in c#?

Tags: c#, .net, serial-port, port

I am writing a serial communication application C# to C.
Where I am trying to write the following `byte[]` array over the serial port.
**Byte Array**
    data = 0x01, 0x01, 0x03, 0x00, 0x01,0x05, 0x00, 0x44, 0x33, 0x48, 0x45, 0x4c, 0x4c, 0x4f 
**C# SerialPort Code :**

```
port.DiscardOutBuffer();
port.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
port.Write("\n");
port.DiscardOutBuffer();
```

On the reciever side, i am reading using a c application.
**I have below questions**.

- Why do the first two bytes of data is being skipped.?
  If I change the first 2 bytes (0x01, 0x01) to some other data it works fine.
- Second, if I remove the 3rd line **port.Write("\n");** .The data is not being read on the c application.
- Is there any particular pattern restriction while transmitting data over the serial port?
- After writing the byte array an additional newline character is a must?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While you do not give enough info to really know what is going on here, I can address your general question.

For many historical reasons, serial ports often do not act as you think they might.  You might start by thinking that the will send and receive data as series of bytes without concern for the value of those bytes.  But for decades serial ports were the primary in/out for computers, so in many cases they act as a **console** device.

So, many characters are treated in special ways.  I believe the last question you ask, about the newline being required, is yes.  This could be handled special either at the sending side (nothing is sent out the port until the newline is sent), or the receiving side (characters are buffered until a newline is received, then the bytes will be delivered to the receiving program).

You may find that carriage return (\r) characters are added before or after the newline.  In some odd cases you might find that every character you send gets sent back to you ("echo").  These all go back to the days the console being used for interaction -- including the use of teletype machines.  Some characters act as "flow control", which can be confusing too.

You probably need some details on how you open the ports to make sure it transmits and receives binary data transparently, and you may want to set the receive timeout to zero to allow bytes to be received immediately.  Check out the WinAPI calls SetCommState() & SetCommTimeouts().

Comment: Thanks for the valuable information,in certain aspects i am clear about the answer to my questions.Yes  i have not provided much information in detail as i want a brief idea about the concepts. Thank You for your kind support and help,really appreciate it a lot.